# Selenium + WebDriver:: please suggest library WebDriver

Tags: php, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am going to move to Selenium2 and use WebDriver for testing.

I found 3 implementation of WebDriver for PHP.

- https://github.com/chibimagic/WebDriver-PHP/
- http://code.google.com/p/php-webdriver-bindings/
- https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver

Please suggest library for PHP and what is the main difference between them?

Answer (score 1):

Would take the last from facebook.

Then again you will have to try them out and decide yourself.

PHP for Webdriver will always be a work around,

I suggest you invest time in java and use Webdriver there.

Answer (score 0):

see below link

https://www.facebook.com/WebDriver/posts/204372046330714

Answer (score 0):

I've been using the Facebook drivers for about 2 months now and have had a good experience so far

I really liked the fact that the method names are very similar to the JSONWIREPROTOCOL
http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol

This makes it easy to look up a command on the protocol page and try and use that command in PHP, you also have an idea of what exceptions will be thrown.

So if you want to find an element on the page, the protocol suggests this...

http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol#/session/:sessionId/element

You choose a strategy on how to locate the element and then build up your command from that...

`$session->element('id', 'my_div_id');`

Bit of a crappy example but hopefully you get the message.